# Mac override window maximize button c++

Tags: c++, macos

I am writing an application, and I want to change the default behavior of the Window Maximize button on Mac.
Since few latest versions of MacOS it defaults to putting the app in fullscreen mode, however it's not what I want.
I want the same behavior as in Windows OS.

I'm using C++.
Ideally what I want is to intercept some window function callback, disable entering fullscreen and instead just maximize the window to entire desktop working area.
How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be difficult to help you since there's no native C++ binding for Cocoa. If you're programming using C++, you must be using some third-party library like Qt or SDL or something like that, but you neglect to tell us what that is.

Also, macOS doesn't have and never has had a "maximize" feature, let alone one like Windows. It has a zoom operation on windows, but that's not the same thing. It's simply an automated resize, it doesn't put the window into a mode where it's locked to the new size until it's restored.

Anyway, to achieve what you want, you should set the window's `collectionBehavior` property to include `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenNone` and **not** `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary` or `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary`. So, in Objective-C(++):

```
window.collectionBehavior &= ~(NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary);
window.collectionBehavior |= NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenNone;
```

If your window is defined in a NIB, you can set its Full Screen behavior to None in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: Thanks, was just able to figure it out on my own. BTW. I'm using my own game engine - http://esenthel.com/

Answer (score 0):

Setting this for NSWindow did the trick:

```
   self.collectionBehavior|=NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenNone;
```